# Issue with arm and x86 in blackberry10 wikitude app

Tags: c++, blackberry-10, augmented-reality, wikitude

I am working on a Blackberry 10 app using wikitude SDK. I am using the documentation on the website and adding the libraries to the project . When the project is built , I am getting an error with "ntox86-ld" . I am new to this and cannot debug the error. The error is:

```
     19:53:36 **** Build of configuration Simulator-Debug for project ARCascadesProject ****
       make -j4 Simulator-Debug 
     make -C .//translations -f Makefile update
     cd x86 && D:/bbndk/host_10_2_0_15/win32/x86/usr/bin/qmake -spec blackberry-x86-qcc ../ARCascadesProject.pro  CONFIG+=debug_and_release CONFIG+=simulator
     make[1]: Entering directory `D:/BB_10_Workspace/ARCascadesProject/translations'
     D:/bbndk/host_10_2_0_15/win32/x86/usr/bin/lupdate ARCascadesProject.pro
     Updating 'ARCascadesProject.ts'...
     Found 1 source text(s) (0 new and 1 already existing)
     make[1]: Leaving directory `D:/BB_10_Workspace/ARCascadesProject/translations'
     make -C .//translations -f Makefile release
     make[1]: Entering directory `D:/BB_10_Workspace/ARCascadesProject/translations'
     D:/bbndk/host_10_2_0_15/win32/x86/usr/bin/lrelease ARCascadesProject.pro
     Updating 'D:/BB_10_Workspace/ARCascadesProject/translations/ARCascadesProject.qm'...
Generated 0 translation(s) (0 finished and 0 unfinished)
Ignored 1 untranslated source text(s)
  make[1]: Leaving directory `D:/BB_10_Workspace/ARCascadesProject/translations'
   make -C ./x86 -f Makefile debug
   make[1]: Entering directory `D:/BB_10_Workspace/ARCascadesProject/x86'
      make -f Makefile.Debug
  make[2]: Entering directory `D:/BB_10_Workspace/ARCascadesProject/x86' 
  D:/bbndk/host_10_2_0_15/win32/x86/usr/bin/moc.exe -DQT_NO_IMPORT_QT47_QML -DQ_OS_BLACKBERRY -DQT_DECLARATIVE_DEBUG -DQT_DECLARATIVE_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -DQT_SHARED -I../../../bbndk/target_10_2_0_1155/qnx6/usr/share/qt4/mkspecs/blackberry-x86-qcc -I../../ARCascadesProject -I../../../bbndk/target_10_2_0_1155/qnx6/usr/include/qt4/QtCore -I../../../bbndk/target_10_2_0_1155/qnx6/usr/include/qt4/QtDeclarative -I../../../bbndk/target_10_2_0_1155/qnx6/usr/include/qt4 -I../src -Io-g/.moc -I../../../bbndk/target_10_2_0_1155/qnx6/usr/include -I../../../bbndk/target_10_2_0_1155/qnx6/usr/include/freetype2 -I. -D__QNXNTO__ ../src/applicationui.hpp -o o-g/.moc/moc_applicationui.cpp
  qcc -Vgcc_ntox86 -Wno-psabi -lang-c++ -fstack-protector -fstack-protector-all -g -Wno-psabi -Wall -W -D_REENTRANT -DQT_NO_IMPORT_QT47_QML -DQ_OS_BLACKBERRY -DQT_DECLARATIVE_DEBUG -DQT_DECLARATIVE_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -DQT_SHARED -I../../../bbndk/target_10_2_0_1155/qnx6/usr/share/qt4/mkspecs/blackberry-x86-qcc -I../../ARCascadesProject -I../../../bbndk/target_10_2_0_1155/qnx6/usr/include/qt4/QtCore -I../../../bbndk/target_10_2_0_1155/qnx6/usr/include/qt4/QtDeclarative -I../../../bbndk/target_10_2_0_1155/qnx6/usr/include/qt4 -I../src -Io-g/.moc -I../../../bbndk/target_10_2_0_1155/qnx6/usr/include -I../../../bbndk/target_10_2_0_1155/qnx6/usr/include/freetype2 -I. -x c++-header -c ../precompiled.h -o o-g/.obj/ARCascadesProject.gch/c++
  qcc -Vgcc_ntox86 -c -Wc,-include -Wc,o-g/.obj/ARCascadesProject -Wno-psabi -lang-c++ -fstack-protector -fstack-protector-all -g -Wno-psabi -Wall -W -D_REENTRANT -DQT_NO_IMPORT_QT47_QML -DQ_OS_BLACKBERRY -DQT_DECLARATIVE_DEBUG -DQT_DECLARATIVE_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -DQT_SHARED -I../../../bbndk/target_10_2_0_1155/qnx6/usr/share/qt4/mkspecs/blackberry-x86-qcc -I../../ARCascadesProject -I../../../bbndk/target_10_2_0_1155/qnx6/usr/include/qt4/QtCore -I../../../bbndk/target_10_2_0_1155/qnx6/usr/include/qt4/QtDeclarative -I../../../bbndk/target_10_2_0_1155/qnx6/usr/include/qt4 -I../src -Io-g/.moc -I../../../bbndk/target_10_2_0_1155/qnx6/usr/include -I../../../bbndk/target_10_2_0_1155/qnx6/usr/include/freetype2 -I. -o o-g/.obj/applicationui.o ../src/applicationui.cpp
  qcc -Vgcc_ntox86 -c -Wc,-include -Wc,o-g/.obj/ARCascadesProject -Wno-psabi -lang-c++ -fstack-protector -fstack-protector-all -g -Wno-psabi -Wall -W -D_REENTRANT -DQT_NO_IMPORT_QT47_QML -DQ_OS_BLACKBERRY -DQT_DECLARATIVE_DEBUG -DQT_DECLARATIVE_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -DQT_SHARED -I../../../bbndk/target_10_2_0_1155/qnx6/usr/share/qt4/mkspecs/blackberry-x86-qcc -I../../ARCascadesProject -I../../../bbndk/target_10_2_0_1155/qnx6/usr/include/qt4/QtCore -I../../../bbndk/target_10_2_0_1155/qnx6/usr/include/qt4/QtDeclarative -I../../../bbndk/target_10_2_0_1155/qnx6/usr/include/qt4 -I../src -Io-g/.moc -I../../../bbndk/target_10_2_0_1155/qnx6/usr/include -I../../../bbndk/target_10_2_0_1155/qnx6/usr/include/freetype2 -I. -o o-g/.obj/main.o ../src/main.cpp
  qcc -Vgcc_ntox86 -c -Wc,-include -Wc,o-g/.obj/ARCascadesProject -Wno-psabi -lang-c++ -fstack-protector -fstack-protector-all -g -Wno-psabi -Wall -W -D_REENTRANT -DQT_NO_IMPORT_QT47_QML -DQ_OS_BLACKBERRY -DQT_DECLARATIVE_DEBUG -DQT_DECLARATIVE_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -DQT_SHARED -I../../../bbndk/target_10_2_0_1155/qnx6/usr/share/qt4/mkspecs/blackberry-x86-qcc -I../../ARCascadesProject -I../../../bbndk/target_10_2_0_1155/qnx6/usr/include/qt4/QtCore -I../../../bbndk/target_10_2_0_1155/qnx6/usr/include/qt4/QtDeclarative -I../../../bbndk/target_10_2_0_1155/qnx6/usr/include/qt4 -I../src -Io-g/.moc -I../../../bbndk/target_10_2_0_1155/qnx6/usr/include -I../../../bbndk/target_10_2_0_1155/qnx6/usr/include/freetype2 -I. -o o-g/.obj/moc_applicationui.o o-g/.moc/moc_applicationui.cpp
  qcc -Vgcc_ntox86 -lang-c++ -Wl,-rpath-link,D:/bbndk/target_10_2_0_1155/qnx6/x86/lib -Wl,-rpath-link,D:/bbndk/target_10_2_0_1155/qnx6/x86/usr/lib -Wl,-rpath-link,D:/bbndk/target_10_2_0_1155/qnx6/x86/usr/lib/qt4/lib -o o-g/ARCascadesProject o-g/.obj/applicationui.o o-g/.obj/main.o o-g/.obj/moc_applicationui.o    -LD:/bbndk/target_10_2_0_1155/qnx6/x86/lib -LD:/bbndk/target_10_2_0_1155/qnx6/x86/usr/lib -LD:/bbndk/target_10_2_0_1155/qnx6/x86/usr/lib/qt4/lib -LD:/bbndk/target_10_2_0_1155/qnx6//usr/lib/qt4/lib -L../Library/lib -lARchitectSDK -lARchitectLibrary -lgameplay -lscreen -lEGL -lGLESv2 -limg -lcrypto -lbbdevice -lcamapi -lfreetype -lmmrndclient -lpng -lbbdata -lwmm -lbb -lbbsystem -lbbcascades -lQtDeclarative -lQtScript -lQtSvg -lQtSql -lsqlite3 -lz -lQtXmlPatterns -lQtGui -lQtNetwork -lsocket -lQtCore -lm -lbps 
D:\bbndk\host_10_2_0_15\win32\x86\usr\bin\ntox86-ld: skipping incompatible ../Library/lib\libARchitectSDK.a when searching for -lARchitectSDK
D:\bbndk\host_10_2_0_15\win32\x86\usr\bin\ntox86-ld: cannot find -lARchitectSDK
D:\bbndk\host_10_2_0_15\win32\x86\usr\bin\ntox86-ld: skipping incompatible ../Library/lib\libARchitectLibrary.a when searching for -lARchitectLibrary 
D :\bbndk\host_10_2_0_15\win32\x86\usr\bin\ntox86-ld: cannot find -lARchitectLibrary
D:\bbndk\host_10_2_0_15\win32\x86\usr\bin\ntox86-ld: skipping incompatible ../Library/lib\libgameplay.a when searching for -lgameplay
D:\bbndk\host_10_2_0_15\win32\x86\usr\bin\ntox86-ld: cannot find -lgameplay
cc: D:/bbndk/host_10_2_0_15/win32/x86/usr/bin/ntox86-ld caught signal 5
 make[2]: *** [o-g/ARCascadesProject] Error 1
 make[2]: Leaving directory `D:/BB_10_Workspace/ARCascadesProject/x86'
 make[1]: *** [debug] Error 2
 make[1]: Leaving directory `D:/BB_10_Workspace/ARCascadesProject/x86'
 make: *** [Simulator-Debug] Error 2

19:54:02 Build Finished (took 25s.979ms)
```

please look into the issue . I am new to this technology I am trying to implement Augmented Reality in bb10 using wikitude , please help I am stuck here?

Comment: When it says skipping, I assume this means it found an ARM library when building an X86 executable.  They do not mix.

Comment: AFAIK armv7 and x86 is somewhere related to OS architecture. As mentioned, I am trying to develop a augmented reality in BB10 using wikitude. It would great if you can please direct me a path to accomplish this.

Answer (score 0):

You are building the target "Simulator-Debug" which is not supported by Wikitude SDK. You will need to build for a device. Change the "Build configuration" under Debug/Run Configurations to  "Device-Debug" or "Device-Release".